# SQLAlchemy: Multiple foreign keys in an association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to store data on currency exchange transactions (e.g. buy 100 USD for 105 GBP). I'm struggling with resolving an error in SQLAlchemy:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Currency.valuations - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'currency_valuations'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.)

I have a table for storing which currencies were transacted and in what amounts, followed by the class/table for currencies:

```
CurrencyValuationTable = Table(
    'currency_valuations',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('purchased_currency', ForeignKey('currencies.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('sold_currency', ForeignKey('currencies.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('purchased_amount', Integer()),
    Column('sold_amount', Integer())
    )

class Currency(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'currencies'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())
    valuations = relationship('Currency', secondary=CurrencyValuationTable, back_populates='currencies')
```

I think I'm missing either the foreign_keys or primaryjoin keywords in CurrencyValuationTable's foreign key columns, but I can't wrap my head around what they are doing or what should be the value for those keywords.